# JavaScript plugin for finding images links in plain-text and converting them to HTML <img> in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, linkify

I have a situation where i need to display images if the chat messages come with image link,currently i am displaying just as image link.

One solution i thought that i will check for lastIndexOf('.') and get the extension and match it within ng-if,but i feel it will not be neat solution.
Hence i am looking for any library or angular built in module which does it for me just like:

> linkify(Linkify is a JavaScript plugin for finding links in plain-text and converting them to HTML  tags)

Answer (score -1):

```
imgify(text) {
    const regexp = /\b(https?:\/\/\S+(?:png|jpe?g|gif)\S*)\b/ig;
    const replace = "<br><img src='$1'>";
    return text.replace(regexp, replace);
}
```